# Adjusting the map's opacity

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hi–I'm trying to set the opacity of a map to `0.6`, so I could draw a polygon with `1.0` opacity on it.

Now, setting the polygon's opacity [is simple](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/adjust-layer-opacity/). Is there a way to alter the map style's opacity (`streets-v10`, in this case)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A style is just a list of layers, you'd need to iterate over all the layers and set their opacity. Something like this:

```
map.getStyle().layers.map((layer) => {
    if (layer.type === 'symbol')  {
        map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, `icon-opacity`, 0.5);
        map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, `text-opacity`, 0.5);
    } else {
        map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, `${layer.type}-opacity`, 0.5);
    }
})
```

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a cleaner way (without looping on a bunch of layers). But, that'll do. Thank you, Andrew.